# How to swap a div's image source with another image on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm having issues changing attributes using jQuery

here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mepygo30/

```
JS:

$("#but1").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', 'css/img1.jpg');
    }, function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', 'css/img2.jpg');
});

HTML:
<body>
     <div id = "but1" class = "button"><img src ="css/img1.jpg"/></div>  
</body
```

In my actual code I created a class for each individual button and put all the attributes in there and separated each button with a different ID.

I want to be able to change the background image of each of the buttons such as "but1" to img2 when my mouse hovers over it and when my mouse leaves it changes back to img1.

Thanks

Edit: SOP for jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( $("#but1").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', 'css/facebook.png');
    }, function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', 'css/facebookbw.png');
    })  );
</script>
```

Comment: You need to quote the arguments to `.attr()`.

Comment: Why don't you just do this with plain CSS instead of jquery? `#but1:hover { background-color: blue;}`

Comment: @Barmar My actual goal was to change the source of an image, but explaining it with the background-color attribute was easier

Comment: So the syntax errors in your question have absolutely no relationship to what you're actually trying to write?

Comment: @Barmar i made a quick edit to better explain my issue.

Comment: `src` has to be on an `<img>` element, not `<div>`.

Comment: @Barmar I just tried adding the "but1" ID to my img tag and it still doesnt work

Comment: Can you make a working example we can fiddle with?

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate IDs when you add the ID to the image.

Comment: You can also use `$(this).find("img").attr('src', 'css/img1.jpg')`

Comment: Your fiddle works, you forgot to include jQuery in the Frameworks menu. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mepygo30/1/

Comment: @Barmar hmm okay. werid, its working for my js fiddle, but its not working when i open the html inside my browser

Comment: Do you have your code inside `$(document).ready()`? That should be SOP for jQuery code.

Comment: @Barmar no i apoligize I'm fairly new to JS and jQuery so not exactly sure how I can call a function

Comment: No, it should be `$(document.ready(function() { $("#but1").hover(...); });`

Comment: Please read a jQuery tutorial, this is one of the first things they teach.

Comment: @Barmar great I'm actually in the middle of finishing up the codeacademy lesson on this subject. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You were close on your javascript. Try changing your script to the following:

```
$("#but1").hover(function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
}, function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: @user3242614 the reason this works is because if you don't put a string in quotes, javascript will look for a variable with that name and throw undefined if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You want like this, right?
DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mepygo30/2/

Make sure you add js link for jquery, and call the function inside..

> $(document).ready(function () { ... });

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but1").hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.office.xerox.com/assets/images/xog/pages/smb/tips/red_square.jpg');
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/square-rounded-xl.png');
    });
});
```